# How to use split?

Tags: javascript, split

I need to break apart a string that always looks like this:

> something -- something_else.

I need to put "something_else" in another input field. Currently, this string example is being added to an HTML table row on the fly like this:

```
tRow.append($('<td>').text($('[id$=txtEntry2]').val()));
```

I figure "split" is the way to go, but there is very little documentation that I can find.

Comment: So what exactly should be put/appended in/to which element?

Comment: Just curious, what did you search for that you didn't find any documentation? I searched on Google for both "javascript split" and "jquery split" and the first result in both cases was the location I linked to.

Comment: And I am sorry but I cannot see how your code example is related to your `split()` problem. Give us more information :)

Comment: I was mistakenly thinking it was a jQuery solution when in fact it's actually a javascript thing. I also saw that documentation but dismissed it too quickly

Comment: You need to remember that jQuery IS javascript - unless you are doing something with selectors (and a few other things that start with $.) you are just doing javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: @GGG Why did you edit? The question makes no sense now.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

Documentation can be found e.g. at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Note that `.split()` is **not** a jQuery method, but a native string method.

If you use `.split()` on a string, then you get an array back with the substrings:

```
var str = 'something -- something_else';
var substr = str.split(' -- ');
// substr[0] contains "something"
// substr[1] contains "something_else"
```

If this value is in some field you could also do:

```
tRow.append($('<td>').text($('[id$=txtEntry2]').val().split(' -- ')[0])));
```

---

Answer (score 25):

If it is the basic JavaScript split function, look at documentation, *[JavaScript split() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)*.

Basically, you just do this:

```
var array = myString.split(' -- ')
```

Then your two values are stored in the array - you can get the values like this:

```
var firstValue = array[0];
var secondValue = array[1];
```

Answer (score 13):

Look in JavaScript split() Method

- [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Usage:

```
"something -- something_else".split(" -- ")
```

Answer (score 0):

> According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), the `split()` method divides a String into an
>   ordered set of substrings, puts these substrings into an array, and
>   returns the array.

### **Example**

```
var str = 'Hello my friend'

var split1 = str.split(' ') // ["Hello", "my", "friend"]
var split2 = str.split('') // ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "m", "y", " ", "f", "r", "i", "e", "n", "d"]
```

### In your case

```
var str = 'something -- something_else'
var splitArr = str.split(' -- ') // ["something", "something_else"]

console.log(splitArr[0]) // something
console.log(splitArr[1]) // something_else
```