# How to hide everything after a dollar sign in a String JQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I have a string like this:

string="Awesome Option +$399.99";

I want to remove the +$399.99  (and any other pricing details) from the string, how would you do that?

Oh and the string could also possibly look like this:

string="#4 Cool Option +$23.99"

Comment: Does it always include the plus sign?

Comment: answer found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555794/how-to-use-split-with-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var text = 'Awesome Option +$399.99';
text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf('+$'));
// text is "Awesome Option "
```

Comment: I like that you've avoided regular expressions, but this would truncate strings such as `Awesome Option +$399.99 More text +$5.99`.

Comment: @Jason your point isn't invalid, per se, but handling such strings wasn't specified as a requirement in the OP.

Comment: Possibly implied: *I want to remove the +$399.99 (**and any other pricing details**) from the string*. Regardless, good answer +1.

Answer (score 3):

You would do: `string.replace(/\s*\+\$.*$/, '')`. Note that this does not depend on jQuery.

This also removes white space in front of the `+$`. If the `+` is optionally there, you'd use `string.replace(/\s*\+?\$.*$/, '')`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var originalString = "Awesome Option +$399.99"
var truncatedString = originalString.split("+")[0]
```

Using the same logic you could extract just the price this way, or both at the same time.