# Split two or more words using jquery?

Tags: jquery, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Split with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555794/how-to-use-split-with-jquery)

How to split two or mor words using Jquery?

For example: allon steve

The array should be [allon,steve]

Thanks

Comment: Please consider searching for answers before posting questions - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555794/how-to-use-split-with-jquery

Comment: Its a simple split. You should learn javascript.

Comment: Considering that you already had `split` in mind, a simple Google search would probably have led you __exactly__ to what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

What about standard javascript `string.split(separator, limit)`, like,

```
var mystring = "allon steve";
var myarray = mystring.split(" ");
```