# Split string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

how to parse this string with java script

19 51 2.108997
20 47 2.1089

like this

```
<span>19 51</span> <span>2.108997</span>     
<span>20 47</span> <span>2.1089</span>
```

Comment: Did you make a typo? I can't find a proper relation. How did 19 51 become 20 46? or is that not important?

Comment: Do you mean `<span>19 51</span> <span>...</span>` and `<span>20 47</span> <span>...</span>`??

Comment: Parse what into what? If you just want to split on a separator, there is a standard function for that, and you should look it up.

Comment: Are you trying to convert a string of the top form into the bottom form? Could you describe a more general case? For example, what might happen if there were more than 2 spaces in a line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use split?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555794/how-to-use-split)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery..

```
var input = '19 51 2.108997\n20 47 2.1089';
var lines = input.split('\n');
var output = '';
$.each(lines, function(key, line) {
    var parts = line.split(' ');
    output += '<span>' + parts[0] + ' ' + parts[1] + '</span><span>' + parts[2] + '</span>\n';
});
$(output).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Also, note that the `lines` variable will be a zero-based array after the second line, so you can access individual elements that were matched (each newline in the above example) in the following manner: `lines[0]`, `lines[1]` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var myString = "19 51 2.108997";
var stringParts = myString.split(" ");
var html = "<span>" + stringParts[0] + " " + stringParts[1] + "</span> <span>" + stringParts[2] + "</span";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var wrapper = $(document.body);

strings = [
    "19 51 2.108997",
    "20 47 2.1089"
];

$.each(strings, function(key, value) {
    var tmp = value.split(" ");
    $.each([
        tmp[0] + " " + tmp[1],
        tmp[2]
    ], function(key, value) {
        $("<span>" + value + "</span>").appendTo(wrapper);
    }); 
});
```