# Using split, but can only get the first [0] value

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am storing multiple values in a select option and trying to get the all the values separately by splitting the value.  Split seems to work as I can get the first [0] value, but I am not getting any value after that.  It alerts back as undefined.  Code below. Thanks.

```
function roi_calc(e) {
var merchant_option = $(e).prev('td').prev('td').prev('td').find('select').val();
if (merchant_option!='Merchant') {
    var value_input = $(e).prev('td').prev('td').find('input').val();
    if ((value_input!='') && (value_input!='Value')) {
        var price_input = $(e).prev('td').find('input').val();
         if ((price_input!='') && (price_input!='Price')) {
            alert ('Merchant value = '+merchant_option);
            //var price_arr = new Array();//tried setting array first, but same results
            var price_arr = price_input.split(',',3);
            //alert (price_arr);//alerts '1'
            alert (price_arr[0]);//working - alerts '1'
            alert (price_arr[1]);//not working - undefined
            alert (price_arr[2]);//not working - undefined
            }
            else {alert ('Price must be entered.');}
        }
        else {alert ('Value must be entered.');}
    }
    else {alert ('Merchant must be selected');}
//alert (row_option);
```

}

HTML

```
<table style="width: 600px;">
<tr>
<td>
    <select>
        <option>Merchant</option>
        <option value="1,2,3,4">1</option>
        <option value="5,6,7,8">2</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td><input value="Value"></td>
<td><input value="Price"></td>
<td onclick="roi_calc(this);"> R.O.I </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

on jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/upywN/

FOUND THE ANSWER.  Stupid mistake on my part.
I was splitting price_input, but needed to be splitting merchant_option  stupid mistake  sorry to waste everyone's time.

Comment: What is the actual value of `price_input` that you get?

Comment: before I split it it alerts 1,2,3,4

Comment: That's strange, in Chrome DevTools' console, I get `"1,2,3,4".split(',',3);` -> `["1", "2", "3"]`. Which browser are you using?

Comment: There is something more going on here. Could you set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows your code in action?

Comment: sure.  I can do that.  I'll link back.

This is all I am trying to do.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2555830/631642

Comment: found the answer.  stupid mistake on my part

Answer (score 1):

this is typically **invalid HTML**

```
<option value="1,2,3,4">1</option>
```

see the property of [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/option)

instead you should use [`multiple select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/select)  like this

`<select multiple="multiple">`

Comment: alert ('Merchant value = '+merchant_option);
alerts out 1,2,3,4
so, I am getting the value I want.

Comment: nope.  that just selects multiple options.  I need to get the values from one option and split them so instead of the string '1,2,3,4' I have an array of '1,2,3,4'

Comment: I mean an array of '1','2','3','4'

Answer (score 0):

Update: You are capturing the 'selected value' (ie. '1' not '1,2,3,4') form

```
<option value="1,2,3,4">1</option>
```

But you have to split 'text' part (i.e. '1,2,3,4').

You can use Javascript for grabbing the 'text' part of option like this:

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');  // 'list' is the id of select element
var text = list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;
//And now use your split
var price_arr = text.split(',',3);
```