# How to use split()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here are the strings like this

```
var a = ".fontlist-1 .fontlist-2";
var b = ".fontlist-1 .fontlist-3";
var c = ".fontlist-1 .fontlist-4";
```

What I need is how can I use the split() method and get only the second word in the string. For the above strings, I need only the second words( ie., .fontlist-2, .fontlist-3, .fontlist-4). How can I split and get that word? If you need any more information, I can give you.

One more thing.
At some situation, If I have string like this.

```
var a = ".fontlist-1"
```

Your code must give me the .fontlist-1 word then. Will it be possible?

Could anyone guide me? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split Come on, guys, RESEARCH.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Split with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555794/how-to-use-split-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`".fontlist-1 .fontlist-2".split(/\s+/)[1]` gives you the second word of the string, in this case `.fontlist-2`. You *could* have [found it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20split).

Well, what the heck ... for a, b, and c try:

```
[a,b,c]
   .map(function(el){return el.split(/\s+/).pop();})
   .join(' ');
//=> ".fontlist-2 .fontlist-3 .fontlist-4"
```

Comment: I think he wants to split on the space, including the `.` in the word.

Comment: Will this code work when I have string like this var a = ".fontlist-1". In that case I need that ".fontlist-1"

Comment: @mk: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @mk: No, it won't. Use `split(/\s+/).pop()` instead.