# Geting the words after splitting a string

Tags: javascript

So I have a paragraph of string and need to separate it by period. How do I get the first 2 sentence?

Here is what I have :

```
var text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."

text.split(".");
for (i=0;i <2;i++) {
   //i dont know what to put here to get the sentence
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for answering my question

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use split?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555794/how-to-use-split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First two sentences should be:

```
 text.split('.').slice(0,2).join('. ');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/yfRyE/).

References:

- [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 0):

Split returns an array, so you need to assign that to a variable. You can then use the array accessor syntax `array[0]` to get the value at that position:

```
var text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."

var sentences = text.split(".");
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var currentSentence  = sentences[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns an array, so :

```
var myarray = text.split(".");

for (i=0;i <myarray.length;i++) {
    alert( myarray[i] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` isn't to be confused with jQuery, it's actually a JavaScript function that returns an array of strings - you can see an introduction to it here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Here's the code that would make your example work:

```
var text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."

// Note the trailing space after the full stop.
// This will ensure that your strings don't start with whitespace.
var sentences = text.split(". ");

// This stores the first two sentences in an array
var first_sentences = sentences.slice(0, 2);

// This loops through all of the sentences
for (var i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
  var sentence = sentences[i]; // Stores the current sentence in a variable.
  alert(sentence); // Will display an alert with your sentence in it.
}​
```