# Split Javascript string containing single backslash to two strings

Tags: javascript

Consider this below string in JavaScript:

```
"TEST NAME\TEST ADDRESS"
```

*(it contains only one "\" which cannot be changed).*

Now, this above string needs to be split into two string by "\" char.

Resulting strings:

```
"TEST NAME"
"TEST ADDRESS"
```

How, can this be done in JavaScript?

Comment: string.split("/") where string is a variable that contains your text, that will return an array

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: @Juhana for a second I thought Im writing another syntax but fixed it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split this string with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96428/how-do-i-split-this-string-with-javascript)

Comment: use split() `var a = "TEST NAME/TEST ADDRESS".split('/'); alert(a[0] + 'and ' + a[1]);`

Comment: @Ahmad Fair enough, although regex is rather overkill in this case

Comment: Have you actually searched for `split string in javascript` with your favorite search engine?

Comment: `'TEST NAME/TEST ADDRESS'.split('/')`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use split?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555794/how-to-use-split)

Comment: Sorry guys, I meant a "BACK SLASH" in the question, but, by mistake, used "FORWARD SLASH". I want answer for "BACK SLASH"

Comment: "FILEUPLOADS\TravelOCity_sri\src\com\travelocityapp22\commonmodule\dto" how to split the above string using '\' ?

Answer (score 15):

Do like this:

```
var str = "TEST NAME/TEST ADDRESS";
var res = str.split("/");
```

You will get first part on res[0] and second part on res[1].

Comment: Please give solution for "BACKSLASH"

Comment: @PriteshPatel Try 
var str = "TEST NAME\\TEST ADDRESS";
var res = str.split("\\");

Comment: @NDM Now I understand what do you mean by Vampire.

Comment: @Al-Amin, the problem is that the source contains only Single Backslash.

Comment: @PriteshPatel: `"\\"` creates a string with a single backslash. Since the backslash is the [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), it has to be escaped.

Answer (score 6):

```js
var str = "TEST NAME\\TEST ADDRESS"; // Show: TEST NAME\TEST ADDRESS
console.log(str);
var res = str.split("\\");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var mystring = 'TEST NAME/TEST ADDRESS';
var splittable = mystring.split('/');
string1 = splittable[0];
string2 = splittable[1];
```

Comment: Please give solution for "BACKSLASH".

Comment: incase anyone still looking for the backslash solution str.split("\\");

Answer (score 2):

**For Backslash or For URL or For Path:**

If Suppose, we are getting path like below:

```
C:\fakepath\yourImage.jpeg
```

If you want to take filename alone,

```
var scanImagePath = C:\fakepath\yourImage.jpeg;
choosedFileName = scanImagePath.substring(scanImagePath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, scanImagePath.length);
```